# How do I use a view helper inside a form in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers, service-locator, zend-form-select

I have a view helper that returns an array called `$this->getTypes();`

I've set it up as an invokable:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'getTypes' => 'Account\View\Helper\GetTypes',
    ),
),
```

If I echo it in the view can see the array, but in the form it fails.

I would like something like:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name'       => 'type_id',
    'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => 'required',
    ),
    'options'    => array(
        'label'            => 'Type *',
        'value_options'    => $this->getTypes(),
    ),
));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: **you don't**

The medium answer is: to get DB-Values into your `Zend\Form\Element\Select` you have to inject your DB-/Service-Layer into your Form.

The long answer is: written in my Blog post [`Zend\Form\Element\Select` and Database Values](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/)

Comment: this sucks. what if i need to use `$this->getTypes()` in more forms.. , there must be some kind of way to get this done. thanks nonetheless

Comment: Think of it in the OOP Way. It shouldn't be a ViewHelpers job to get a Form populated. Nor shouldn't it be it's job to get the Data for Population. That's a Services Job. Therefore your Form is dependent on the Service and needs to be injected. There's no other way around that and imo that's fine :P

Comment: i end up creating a model class in the `Application\Model` namespace that will hold this logic. I then used a factory to inject the SM into that model and did the logic. Then i injected the factory that holds the model in the form. I like to keep the Service classes to do logic associated with the database (just a preference).